# How can a list of strings be stored in a constexpr context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr, initializer-list

I was converting these tables of docstrings (as a type traits like system) for some domain object classes until I stumpled upon this issue.
Later, I was planning to check at compile time if these special members had documentation written (as a to reason to why I would like it at compile time). 
I created a small example for demonstration:

https://godbolt.org/z/3dX3-e

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct CStr {
    struct M {
      const char* name;
      const char* val;
    };

  constexpr CStr(const std::initializer_list<M>& str) : str_(str) {
  };

  std::initializer_list<M> str_;
};

constexpr CStr cstr_test{ { {"key", "val"} } };

int main() {
  return cstr_test.str_.begin()->name[0];
}
```

Basicly the 3 main compilers seems to treat this case differently, this *seemingly* works on an older [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), but fails to compile when changed to latest version 9.1 (saying the cstr_test line is not a contant expression). On [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc) (*and the one im interested in*) the `initializer_list` gets the size correct but the temporary does not survive to the output. [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) refused to compile, due to a temporary being created. This last thing seems like a hint, and Im suspecting this is what could be happening with [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc) as well but without emitting the error.

The example can be fixed if `std::initializer_list<M>` is changed to just `M`.

A relevant section from the reference might be:

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type const T[N], in which
>   each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions
>   are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original
>   initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as
>   any other temporary object, except that initializing an
>   initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the
>   array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same
>   exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The
>   underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.

**How can a list of objects containing strings be created at compile time ?**

Comment: Can't you use `std::array`, or size might vary?

Comment: @Jarod42 correct, the size varies (depends on the number of documentation items)

Comment: `std::span` (since C++20), and store your data in c-array or `std::array`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't have c++20 yet

Comment: It is mostly pointer+size, that your can rewrite.

Comment: @Jarod42 Im not sure I understand how you would do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` should not be used as storage.

So in your case storage should be done outside of the class. Regular C-array or `std::array` can be used for that.

Then you class may just have view of that data.

C++20 provides [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Prior to C++20, you might do something like:

```
struct CStr {
    struct M {
        const char* name;
        const char* val;
    };

    constexpr CStr(const M* data, std::size_t size) : data(data), size(size) {}

    const M* begin() const { return data; }
    const M* end() const { return data + size; }

    const M* data;
    std::size_t size;
};

 constexpr CStr::M data[]{ { {"key", "val"} } };

 constexpr CStr cstr_test(data, 1);

int main() {
  return cstr_test.begin()->name[0];
}
```

Comment: It looks like constexpr std::initializer_list<CStr::M> data{ {"key", "val"} };  also works

Comment: So im thinking this: isn't there a way to change CStr constructor so it can grab it "directly" like the std::initializer_list (or is that built in by the compiler) ??

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit different approach (IMO your example is over complicated), but C++17 introduces `std::string_view` so this can be handled in simple way without extra classes. Also when you do not know how many elements there are you can use C-like array:

```
const constexpr std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> str_test[] {
    { "a"sv, "alpha"sv },
    { "b"sv, "beta"sv },
    { "c"sv, "siera"sv },
};
```

Live demo [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LtVNRJ1WmlImOCOm) [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/088pSrxzrYB8oPvx) [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/YCiJYO).

Comment: Maybe it looks overcomplicted - this is because i left out an enum member on M struct to simplify a bit. Also, it will be difficult to add 'sv' to all the strings in my actual case.

Comment: `sv` is not obligatory it is just small improvement.

Comment: But other than that, there is not much different than using a const char * - ie. stringview doesn't solve my initial issue.